# Finding the length of the last word input in C. At the while loop part, the if statement never reaches the else part, how to fix that?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, c-strings, function-definition

Finding the length of the last word input in C. At the while loop part, the if statement never reaches the else part, how to fix that?
The output for the input "Hello world" should be 5

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int lsl(char s[]){
    int L;
    char str[5000]={0};
    gets(str);
    
    L = strlen(str);
    int i = L-1;
    while(i>=0){
        if(str[i]!=" ") i--;
        else break;
    }
    printf("%s:\n",str);
    printf("%d:\n",L);
    printf("%d:\n",i);
    printf("%d:\n",L-1-i);
    return L-1-i;
} 

void main(){
    char s[5000];
    lsl(s);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: Unrelated: you the argument `s` to the function if you never use it inside?

Comment: According to your comments below the answers you compared a pointer with an integer. Your compiler should tell you such things. If not, turn up the warning level. For GCC you can use options `-Wall -Wextra`. If your compiler printed some warning, you should read them, understand them and solve them before you run the program.

Answer (score 3):

```
 if(str[i]!=" ")
```

but you mean

```
if(str[i]!=' ')
```

Prefer compile with warnings; this compared the ith character in str with the pointer to the constant string consisting of a single space character. With constant string folding this is not utterly meaningless anymore, but it still won't be true. To get single characters instead of strings, use single quotes.

Comment: That's a sigh mistake o(╥﹏╥)o... thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Secondly the function `lsl`

```
int lsl(char s[]){
```

does not use its parameter `s`. The passed character array is not changed within the function.

Thirdly, the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use the standard C function `fgets`.

In this if statement

```
if(str[i]!=" ") i--;
```

there are compared the character produced by the expression `str[i]`  with the string literal `" "` that used in the condition is converted to the type `char*`.
That is in this if statement there are compared a character and a pointer that does not make a sense. You need to use the integer character constant `' '` instead of the string literal `" "`.

```
if ( str[i] != ' ' ) i--;
```

But in any case the function is incorrect because the user can enter trailing spaces. In this case you will get an incorrect result.

The function can be declared and defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t lsl( char s[], size_t n )
{
    size_t length = 0;
    
    if ( fgets( s, n, stdin ) )
    {
        s[ strcspn( s, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

        size_t i = strlen( s );
        
        while ( i != 0 && isspace( ( unsigned char )s[i -1] ) ) --i;
        
        while ( i != 0 && !isspace( ( unsigned char )s[--i] ) )
        {
            ++length;
        }
    }
    
    return length;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 5000 };
    
    char s[N];
    
    size_t length = lsl( s, N );
    
    if ( length != 0 )
    {
        printf( "The length of the last word in the string \"%s\"\n", s );
        printf( "is %zu\n", length );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter for example the string `"Hello World   "` then the program output will look like

```
The length of the last word in the string "Hello World   "
is 5
```

Comment: One step at a time man. I left the gets method in place because learning is expensive in brain power. (I didn't vote on this answer.)